# Can not figure out how front end template javascript and CSS was wrapped

Tags: javascript, css, frontend

I bought [this template](https://wrapbootstrap.com/theme/boland-minimal-shop-light-dark-WB01P97L2) and am trying to figure out how the developer minified and wrapped the js/css into min.js/min.css. I emailed him and got not response and the Readme doesn't explain this. If anyone has any good tutorials for front end dev wrapping I will happily take them.

Here is how it is organized:

```
boland
  html
  js
    custom
    theme.js
  public
    assets
      css
      js
  scss
    custom
    styles.scss
    style-dark.scss
  gulpfile.js
  package.json
  package-lock.json
  readme.md
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually all you need will be in the package.json file in the "scripts" block.
First you need to go to the root folder of the template and run in terminal
`npm install` or `yarn` (depending which node package manager you have/prefer)
after that you will need to start maybe "gulp watch" to start watching for changes in the sass and js folders which will trigger creation of new files in public/assets folder. maybe you can provide package.json contents.

Comment: Thanks! I will read up on npm. Everything I find seems to point towards npm being what I need.